# Jenkins Android emulator error [ ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED]

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins

**Jenkins v2.32.3** at development environment **CentOS 7 64bit**

Jenkins job fails with following error:

```
[android] Using Android SDK: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5855 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -engine classic -ports 5712,5713 -report-console tcp:5831,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_240_WVGA_android-21_armeabi-v7a_jenkins -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
sh: file: command not found
sh: file: command not found
WARNING: Cannot decide host bitness because $SHELL is not properly defined; 32 bits assumed.
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
       you will have to do at least one of the following:

       - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
       - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.

       Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
       aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
       Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
```

If I set Global Variable `ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT` to `true` than it gives slightly different error

```
WARNING: Cannot decide host bitness because $SHELL is not properly defined; 32 bits assumed.
WARNING: Force to use classic engine to support snapshot.
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU.
```

Jenkins global settings which may impact is set as following:

- `Shell executable` field left blank
- `Android SDK root` field left blank
- `Automatically install Android components when required` checked
- `Keep emulators in the job workspace, in the .android subdirectory,
  to isolate them as much as possible` checked

Comment: Is Jenkins running on a 32- or 64-bit machine?

Comment: 64bit. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: @RobertasSetkus were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @android_student gave up for CentOS 7. Cannot remember what exactly caused it  (had too many issues) but I guess the problem was due to that CentOS used older some lib version and I couldn't/wasn't possible to upgrade. Ended up switching to Ubuntu.